# Ошибка в Scanner

Tags: java

При компиляции, выдаёт вот эти ошибки (на картинке). Как исправить эту ситуацию? Заранее благодарю.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("");
        System.out.print("Введите n");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Результат:");
        Rep(n);
    }
    public static void Rep(int n){
        if (n > 1)
        {
            Rep(n / 8);
            System.out.print(n % 8);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вместо Scanner scanner = new Scanner(""); надо Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); и это не ошибка компиляции

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Дмитрий, почему этот код вообще компилируется? Checked exceptions же?

Comment: @Qwertiy где именно Checked exceptions? в какой строке кода?

Comment: @Дмитрий, не в строке, а в джаве.

Comment: @Qwertiy исключение выбрасывает определенный код. если это Checked exceptions, то это обязательно указано в сигнатуре метода. вот я и спрашиваю, в какой строке приведенного выше кода по вашему мнению вызывается метод, в сигнатуре которого задекларировано Checked exception?  Если вы про NoSuchElementException, то это прямой наследник RuntimeException, следовательно не относится к проверяемым исключениям

Comment: @Дмитрий, мне казалось, создание самого сканера, нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy все дело в том, что сканер - утилитный класс и его конструктор перегружен. когда мы говорим про конструктор, принимающий в аргументы что-либо из пакета io или nio , т.е. File или Path, то закономерно появляются характерные для этих пакетов исключения: IOException, FileNotFoundException. Но в данном случае мы не обращаемся к этому пакету, ведь в аргументы передается System.in, а это не обычный поток, это поток ввода ,который открывает сама JVM, ведь он поддерживается на уровне ос, поэтому сигнатура данного конструктора сканера не содержит никаких задекларированных исключений.

Comment: @Дмитрий, буду знать. только автор же вместо System.in передаёт пустую строку... Впрочем, я вспомнил, что имя файла сканер вроде не принимает, тогда я вообще не понял, что это...

Comment: @Qwertiy у сканера существует конструктор, принимающий String, делегирующий выполнение классу StringReader. данный конструктор также не бросает проверяемых исключений. Просто автор ошибся в реализации. Он хотел получить консольный ввод, а вместо System.in передал в аргументы конструктора String. Именно об этом я и написал в первом комментарии.